# Spring session scope, how to get it to work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application, that is up and running. However, trying to get the cart bit to work is tricky.

I have a component that represents the cart

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class Cart{

    private String user;
    private Map<Item, Integer> items;
    private int numberOfItems;
```

... getters setters

my service is as follows

```
@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements Cart Service {
    
    @Autowired
    Cart cart;
    
    @Override
    public Cart addItem(String user, Item item) {
        // add item to cart
    }
```

controller is as follows:

```
@PostMapping(path="/cart/addItem/{user}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Cart addItem(@PathVariable String user, @RequestBody Item item) {
    return  cartService.addItem(user, item);
}
```

Am I missing some sort of configuration, IT pretty much vanila spring boot app with rest endpoint which basically just passes item through to service.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve (regarding the scope)? What is the error you get? Btw. you don't need the @Component for the cart in the CartServiceImpl.

Comment: I want to maintain sessions scope cart, so that a customer can be adding items to a cart. Like a standard shopping cart app.. 
 I have managed to get it working, but i neded to add (proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) and also copy the cart before sending it back to controller. Not sure why i had to make a copy tho?

I am doing this to get more familiar with spring, so its a learning project.. so im more interested in know why ...

Comment: @user1555190 `TARGET_CLASS` is the default value for `proxyMode`. So omitting it wouldn't make any difference. And you are using `@Component` wrong in `CartServiceImpl`.

Comment: @MinarMahmud yes you are correct, i fixed that.. it was typo.. i agree the TARGET_CLASS is only worth writing if im using the scope annotation... correct?

Comment: @user1555190 that is correct

Comment: I think you need to associate user session with your data, therefore it depends on the session management that you are using, i.e. Cookies, JWT. If you are using JWT you will need to build a service responsible to manage it manually, if you are using cookies, it could be added as one item more.